# How to write template specialization for only SOME of the parameters needed to implement the template

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I have a struct called Vector2 which has a template parameter of T.

(vector2.h)

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector2
{
    T Values[2];

    // ..... methods .....
};
```

I have a method called abs() which is a wrapper to the std::abs() function for most types.

(mymath.h)

```
template <typename T>
static T abs(const T value)
{
    return std::abs<T>(value);
}
```

If I try and pass the vector2 struct to abs() it won't work because the template specialization used in std doesn't include a method for it... obviously, I created it :)

I want to create one.

How can I create a template specialization for a method that takes a struct that requires it's own template parameter?

This was my best guess, but it isn't valid syntax. Is it even possible?

(mymath.cpp)

```
template <typename T>
static Vector2<T> abs<Vector2<T>>(const Vector2<T>& vector)
{
    return vector.abs(); //this exists
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function template can only be fully specialized. You can't partially specialize a function template. However, you *can* specialize class templates and have a `static` member in such a class:

```
template <typename T>
struct abs_helper {
    static T abs(T const value) { return std::abs(value); }
};
template <typename T>
struct abs_helper<Vector2<T>> {
    static Vector2<T> abs(Common::Vector2<T> const& matrix) { return matrix.abs(); }
};

template <typename T>
auto abs(T&& value)
    -> decltype(abs_helper<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>::abs(std::forward<T>(value))) {
    return abs_helper<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>::abs(std::forward<T>(value));
}
```

The forwarding is a bit complicate given that your code uses different approaches to pass arguments for the two different functions: the code tries to mimick this forward (I haven't tried to compile it).

Just to explain a bit what's going on:

1. The `struct abs_helper` is a class template which can be partially specialized and is partially specialized for `Vector2<T>`. The specialization is required to have a static member called `abs()` taking a suitable argument and returning the desired result.
2. The function template `abs()` just forwards to `abs_helper<...>::abs(...)`. Since it forwards its argument it uses prefect forwarding. There are to complications with this forwarding, though:
3. The template argument deduced for `abs()` may contain a reference and/or a `const` which need to be removed before passing it on to the specialized `abs_helper` (otherwise it would require multiple specialization). Thus, any reference is removed followed by removing any `const` using the C++14 type traits using alias (`std::remove_reference_t<T>` and `std::remove_const<T>`).
4. The return type seems to differ. To deal with that the code uses C++11 return-type specification combined with determining the type using `decltype()` based on the actual call of the function.

Comment: Wow. I understand virtually none of that. Ha. Let me have a good read up on this stuff before marking as answer. Thanks for this.

Comment: Might read a bit cleaner if you have `template <typename T> struct abs_helper : abs_helper_impl<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_referece_t<T>>> { };` That way you only have to write that junk once. Just my $0.02. Still good answer

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks for the extra input. The return types are actually the same, you grabbed it before I edited it :) Thank you for the above.

Comment: @Barry: Yes, I see what you mean: it adds another class at the benefit of not repeating the template argument. Well, the code was quickly typed while also trying to follow the discussion at the BSI C++ meeting ;-)

Comment: @DietmarKühl sounds like an exciting discussion ;)

Comment: @DietmarKühl One side question if I may. Where should template specializations be kept? Header or source file?

Comment: @Barry: yes - the current discussion is on [N4162: "Atomic Smart Pointers, rev. 1"](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4162.pdf) which I think is barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: @Beakie: The specialization declaration needs to be visible everywhere it is instantiated. However, the `abs_helper<Vecto2<T>>::abs(...)` implementation _may_ go into a an implementation file assuming you can explicitly instantiate all instances you need (there is still a `T`). Some time ago I wrote something about [source organization for template](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/22/source-organization-of-templates/) which is somewhat applicable.

Comment: You sir, deserve +10. Thanks!

Comment: @DietmarKühl This is such an amazing sentence though: "This righteous code should be supported."

Answer (score 1):

Not being a c++11 guy, my answer looks a bit different and less scientific. You be the judge if this is what you need. I theorized that your Vector2 version of abs would return the length of the vector. As such, the return value of your Vector2::abs would not be T but double (or float or long) depending on what you need, independent of T for your input arguments. Here is my complete test code for that case...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

namespace Common
{
    template <typename T>
    struct Vector2
    {
        T Values[2];

        // ..... methods .....
        double abs() const
        {
            return std::sqrt(Values[0] * Values[0] + Values[1] * Values[1]);
        }
    };


}

template <typename T>
static T abs(const T value)
{
    return std::abs(value);
}

template <typename T>
static double abs(const Common::Vector2<T>& matrix)
{
    return matrix.abs();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Common::Vector2<float> v1;

    v1.Values[0] = 1.0F;
    v1.Values[1] = 1.0F;

    std::cout << "Result = " << abs(v1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is actually more my level of understanding. I myself am not C++11 and I like the simplicity of this approach. Overloading the method instead of using template specialization. How does the compiler know which method to use when a Vector2 of float is passed with no explicit T param passed/defined? (I hope this makes sense)

Comment: There is some notion of "chooses closest match". I thought this /is/ a template specialization, though. I ran with breakpoint in the second abs function and breakpoint got hit. On second thought, maybe it is an overload while I am still inclined to think it is a specialization. Maybe a bit too tired right now...

Comment: I am also unsure! Well, the end result is the same :) Nice one. Though this is how I will implement it, I feel the other answer is the true answer to my actual question so I will leave it answered with the other answer. Thanks again.